# SQL Combine multiple rows from one table into one row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If I have data where the date and time are the same or different as below:

```
ID    Date               LOC
1     2015-12-02 10:05   A
1     2015-12-02 10:05   B2
2     2015-12-02 10:05   D
2     2015-12-02 10:05   A7P 
2     2015-12-02 10:06   AD
```

Is there any way of showing the following:

```
ID   DATE1             LOC1  DATE 2            LOC2  DATE 3            LOC3
1    2015-12-02 10:05  A     2015-12-02 10:05  B2
2    2015-12-02 10:05  D     2015-12-02 10:05  A7P   
2    2015-12-02 10:06  AD
```

So there will be multiple rows where the ID is the same but where the Date and time are different?

I have used the partition example below and this works perfectly for getting data into one row as I originally asked.  But is it possible to show multiple rows when the ID is the same but where the date and time are different.

BELOW IS THE ORIGINAL QUESTION THAT HAS BEEN ANSWERED..

I've looked thrrough all of the answers relating to this question but cant find any code that works and a lot of the questions relate to two tables.

I have one table with multiple rows of data and multiple columns containing different data types e.g.

```
ID    Date               LOC
1     2015-11-05 10:05   A
1     2015-12-02 10:06   B2
2     2015-12-02 10:05   D
2     2015-12-02 10:05   A7P 
2     2015-12-02 10:06   AD
```

I simply require one row for each ID with all of the data in multiple columns e.g.

```
ID   DATE1             LOC1  DATE 2            LOC2  DATE 3            LOC3
1    2015-11-05 10:05  A     2015-12-02 10:06  B2
2    2015-12-02 10:05  D     2015-12-02 10:05  A7P   2015-12-02 10:06  AD
```

These can have duplicated data and one or more rows for the same ID.

I've tried a few pivot/unpivot sql codes but i get an error about different types in the unpivot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a max of 3 pairs of columms?

Comment: Hi.  It varies and could have up to 6.

Comment: if you want the id and datetime to match then just include that in the joins.  The joins are what make things stay on the same row.

Comment: Thanks Hogan.  I tried that and they still showed ondifferent rows.  But when i added the date to the 'PARTITION BY ID, Date' it worked

Comment: yes that makes sense but make sure you add the date into the join or you could have a bug -- I changed the code in my answer.

Comment: Hi Hogan.  I also put the date in the join as you suggested and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic way to this, first make row_number and then do a join

```
WITH TAB_RN AS
(
  SELECT ID, Date, LOC, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date ORDER BY LOC) AS RN
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
)
SELECT T1.ID, 
       T1.Date AS DATE1, T1.LOC AS LOC1,
       T2.Date AS DATE2, T2.LOC AS LOC2,
       T3.Date AS DATE3, T3.LOC AS LOC3
FROM TAB_RN T1
LEFT JOIN TAB_RN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.Date = T2.Date AND T2.RN = 2
LEFT JOIN TAB_RN T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID AND T1.Date = T2.Date AND T3.RN = 3
WHERE T1.RN = 1
```

If you don't know "how many" there will be then you have to use this as a template to make dynamic sql.

Comment: Thanks.  I shall try that.

Comment: often people actually want a comma separated list. there is a trick with the FOR XML to do that does not require knowledge of how many list items there will be.

Comment: Thank you for your help - it works just how i wanted it.

Comment: @Mally -- you should vote the answer up if it helps you and select it as the "correct answer" after have given time for other people to answer.  This is the expectation on this site.

Comment: Ok i will.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to get this but i'm not sure if this one has bugs though.

I created a sample table for testing purposes

```
CREATE TABLE Trace (
    TraceID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , ID INT
    , [Date] DATETIME
    , LOC NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO Trace (ID, [Date], LOC)
VALUES
(1,'2015-12-02 10:05','A'),
(1,'2015-12-02 10:05','B2'),
(2,'2015-12-02 10:05','D'),
(2,'2015-12-02 10:05','A7P'),
(2,'2015-12-02 10:06','AD')
```

and if you wish to get the records base on the number of maximum location count per ID (flexible column), you may try the script below.

```
   -- build up table to keep the values in 1 column and make a flag (StatusCode) out of it
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, StatusCode ORDER BY TraceID, Pos) AS idx
            , *
        INTO #resultBuildUp 
        FROM (
                SELECT
                    TraceID
                    , 2 AS [Pos]
                    , [ID]
                    , 'LOC' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, [Date] ORDER BY TraceID))) AS StatusCode
                    , LOC AS [val]
                FROM Trace
            UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    TraceID
                    , 1 AS [Pos]
                    , [ID]
                    , 'DATE ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, [Date] ORDER BY TraceID))) AS StatusCode
                    , REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),[Date],111),'/','-') + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),[Date],108) AS [val]
                FROM Trace
        ) AS T

    --this is a builder to create the "select" columns for PIVOT

        SELECT
            StatusCode
        INTO #tmpDistinctColumns
        FROM #resultBuildUp
        GROUP BY
            StatusCode
        ORDER BY 
            min(TraceID)
            , min(Pos)

        DECLARE @distinct NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

        SET @distinct = (SELECT '[' + StatusCode + '],' AS [text()] FROM #tmpDistinctColumns FOR XML PATH(''))
        SET @distinct = SUBSTRING(@distinct, 0, LEN(@distinct))

-- and lastly, the pivot query wherein I hid the position modifier(idx) for the query

EXEC ('
SELECT
    ID
    , ' + @distinct + '
FROM (
    SELECT
        idx,
        ID,
        StatusCode,
        val
    FROM #resultBuildUp
) AS s 
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Val)
    FOR StatusCode IN (' + @distinct + ')
) AS pvt
')

-- drop all temporary tables built from above script
drop table #resultBuildUp
drop table #tmpDistinctColumns
```

the "time" specified in your requirement has been considered as well, the result should be like below

[image]